# Does Variable Minion Type empower me to realise my Tron-like character?

Tags: character-creation, optimization, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, vehicles

I am making a character that has some Tron-like abilities. She is more like a Green Lantern, but with a tron-like theme (not based on Tron, though some effects are for coolness). In any case one of the things she can do is create virtually anything she has the plans of.

I am trying to avoid using the Variable Power if I can, and so for vehicles she can create I am looking at Summon Vehicle. I put Variable Type: General (Light Based Vehicles) on it. Do I need multiple minions to create more than one type of vehicle? Or does Variable Minion Type allow me to alter the minion type as needed?

If I need Multiple, then I will end up having to use the Variable Power, as multiple will still have some limits on the number of 'types' of vehicles.

Comment: Hello, I tried to focus your title on the issue that you are facing, feel free to edit if you don't think that it represents your question. Also, welcome to rpg.se. Please take the [tour] :)

Answer (score 6):

### You're Good

**Multiple Minions** is used to summon multiple different things that can be present at the same time.

> Multiple Minions: You can summon more than one minion. Each application of this extra doubles your total number of minions. So, for example, with Summon 6, you summon a single 90-point minion. With Multiple Minions 1, you can summon two 90-point minions, with Multiple Minions 2, four minions, and so forth. It requires a standard action to summon each minion unless you also have the Horde extra (see previous). +2 cost per rank.

**Variable Type** is used to summon a variety of things that have different abilities.

> Variable Type: Minions are normally identical in terms of traits, although they may differ cosmetically. With this modifier you can summon different minions of a general type (like elementals, birds, fish, etc.), or even a broad type (like animals, demons, humanoids, etc.). General Type: +1 cost per rank. Broad Type: +2 cost per rank.

For your stated goal, Variable Type is the correct modifier.

---

Note that it does not change the core rules of the power, notably the recovery time:

> Incapacitated minions disappear. They recover normally and you cannot summon an incapacitated minion until it has completely recovered.